# Martingale problem with some conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, independence

> $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are independent iid random variables, $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ 
>    (iid random variables) are independent from $X_{n+1},X_{n+2}...$   for every n.
>
> $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is a generated sigma algebra where $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n},Y_{1},...,Y_{n})$ and $Z_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}Y_{k}$. We also know 
>   $\mathbb{E}(X_{n})=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(\left|X_{n}Y_{n}\right|)<\infty$ for every n.
>
> How can I prove $(Z_{n},\mathcal{F}_{n})$ is a  martingale?

Here is my results so far:

$$
\begin{split}
E(Z_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})
 &= E(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_{k}Y_{k}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})\\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} E(X_kY_k\mid\mathcal{F}_n) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}Y_{k}+E(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})\\
 &= Z_{n}+E(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})
\end{split}
$$

I know I should prove somehow $E(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})=0$. I tried Law of total expectation but I didn't see how it would have helped. I know I should use the fact that  $E(X_{n})=0$ and I should use the independence of the random variables but I've just stopped here. Can someone help me? Is it a good solution so far anyway?

Comment: I would say $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$, so $$\mathbb E[X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[X_{n+1}]\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] = 0$$ but I think this is incorrect because $X_{n+1}$ and $Y_{n+1}$ are not necessarily independent.

Comment: $X_{n+1} Y_{n+1}$ is indepndent from $\mathcal{F}_n$, and so $$\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1} Y_{n+1} \mid Y_n) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1} Y_{n+1})= \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}) \mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1})=0.$$

Comment: But how do you know $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})=\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1})\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1})$?

Comment: I asked my former teacher. He said it was a wrong question with missing conditions. With these conditions it is not necessarily a martingale. I had the same opinion, therefore this is the reason why I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}$ be an i.i.d. centered, square integrable sequence and let $Y_i=X_i$. Then all the conditions are fulfilled but 
$$
\mathbb E\left[X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n\right]= 
\mathbb E\left[X_{n+1}^2\mid\sigma\left(X_1,\dots,X_n\right)\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_{n+1}^2\right].
$$